# 'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type' in compiling FreeBSD custom system call

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am getting compilation error when I compile this code:

```
#include <sys/param.h> 
#include <sys/system.h>

struct syshello_args 
{
   char *buf;
};

int sys_myhello(p, uap)
struct proc* p; struct syshello_args* uap;
{
   sprintf(uap->buf, "Hello");
   p->p_retval[0]=0;
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting many errors:

I am not familiar with C language at all. I found this example in a couple of tutorials but
it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me fixing the error.

Thank you

Comment: I think your tutorials are weird. Try to find another one.

At least, buf in struct syshello_args can be located nowhere (there is no malloc in your example). Second, writing argument types after closing brace is a really old way.

Also, beginning C with system calls is not a good idea, in my opinion.

Comment: They are! This is just the implementation of the system call which is suppose to print a message. It's for freeBSD 4.2

Comment: @JIghtuse: `p` and `uap` are parameters to `sys_myhello`; the caller should have passed in valid values. It's an old-style function definition; the modern equivalent is `int sys_myhello(struct proc* p, struct syshello_args* uap) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, but I can't use it in the FreeBSD 4.2.